# Remove empty option from listData at CGridView filter

Tags: yii, filter, cgridview

I would like to remove the empty or first option of list data value.
I have Bankaccount model and it has a list, so I need to prevent from users to select all.

I already selected the first one of that list as a default, but now the problem is the empty option that can let user to select all  Bankaccount still exist, so how can I remove.

This is my code

```
array(
        'name' => 'bank_account_id',
        'type' => 'raw',
        'value' => '$data->bankaccount->BankAccountName', 
        'filter' => Chtml::listData(Bankaccount::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'name  DESC')), "id", "BankAccountName"),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [this method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#renderFilterCellContent-detail) that generates filter, you will see that it always adds empty option when it gets an array on input. So, the only way to hide empty option is to generate selectbox manually:

```
'filter' => CHtml::activeDropDownList(Bank::model(), 'bank_account_id',
    Chtml::listData(Bankaccount::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'name  DESC')), "id", "BankAccountName"),
    ),
),
```

Using CHtml::activeDropDownList will give you **Bank[bank_account_id]** in the selectbox name.

Answer (score 0):

for the filter part,

```
'filter' => Chtml::dropdownList('Bank[bank_account_id]' , 'selectedDefault',
    Chtml::listData(Bankaccount::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'name  DESC')), "id", "BankAccountName"),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Thank you tinybyte, yes it removed the empty option but the filtering is not working  and that is the result<select name="bank_account_id" id="bank_account_id">
<option value="1">bank 1</option>
<option value="2">bank 2</option>
</select>

Comment: here is how it should be: <select name="Bank[bank_account_id]">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="1" selected="selected"> bank 1 </option>
 <option value="2">bank 2 </option>
</select>

Comment: then you should name it : `Bank[bank_account_id]`, this should fix your filter, check your ajax parameters sent by the gridview